# Redirecting using getServerSideProps returns an error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm trying to redirect to the `/chat` page when I'm logged in. I'm using auth0 to handle authentification. Not sure what the error is because I'm returning an empty string for props. The error however doesn't affect the website and redirection works fine. The wrong type is the main problem here. I'm not entirely sure what interface to define here.

```
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  const { req, res } = context;
  const session = await getSession(req, res);

  if (session) {
    return {
      redirect: {
        destination: "/chat",
      },
    };
  }

  return {
    props: {},
  };
};
```

So far I've tried to go into `GetServerSideProps` types and adjusting context accordingly but it doesn't work. I get the following error:

> Type '(context: GetServerSidePropsContext<ParsedUrlQuery, PreviewData>) => Promise<{ redirect: { destination: string; }; props?: undefined; } | { ...; }>' is not assignable to type 'GetServerSideProps'.
> Type 'Promise<{ redirect: { destination: string; }; props?: undefined; } | { props: {}; redirect?: undefined; }>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<GetServerSidePropsResult<{ [key: string]: any; }>>'.
> Type '{ redirect: { destination: string; }; props?: undefined; } | { props: {}; redirect?: undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'GetServerSidePropsResult<{ [key: string]: any; }>'.
> Type '{ redirect: { destination: string; }; props?: undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'GetServerSidePropsResult<{ [key: string]: any; }>'.
> Type '{ redirect: { destination: string; }; props?: undefined; }' is not assignable to type '{ props: { [key: string]: any; } | Promise<{ [key: string]: any; }>; }'.
> Types of property 'props' are incompatible.
> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type '{ [key: string]: any; } | Promise<{ [key: string]: any; }>'.ts(2322)

This is the code above getServerSideProps just in case:

```
import Head from "next/head";
import Link from "next/link";
import { useUser } from "@auth0/nextjs-auth0/client";
import { getSession } from "@auth0/nextjs-auth0";
import { GetServerSideProps } from "next";

export default function Home() {
  const { isLoading, error, user } = useUser();

  if (isLoading) return <div>Loading...</div>;
  if (error) return <div>{error.message}</div>;

  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>Ask Me - Login or Signup</title>
      </Head>
      <div>
        <div>
          {user && <Link href="/api/auth/logout">Logout</Link>}
          {!user && (
            <>
              <Link
                href="/api/auth/login"
              >
                Login
              </Link>
              <Link
                href="/api/auth/signup" >
                Signup
              </Link>
            </>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to include `statusCode` prop in your redirect response. In this case you want to use temporary redirect code:

```js
return {
  redirect: {
    destination: "/chat",
    statusCode: 302
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! Is there a documentation to read more about auth0 and typescript?

Comment: This error had nothing to do with auth0. The expected return type comes from Next `GetServerSideProps` type. You can click on that type in your IDE to inspect all possible return options.